# "requested module differs from name found in the interface file"

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

What I want is: `cabal` to build my modules; `make` to build this one script.

The script links to Objective-C (see https://github.com/mchakravarty/language-c-inline/tree/master/tests/objc/marshal-array). when I build the script, it fails on the import:

```
$ make
Main.hs:1:1:
    Bad interface file: dist/build/Commands/OSX/Events.hi
        Something is amiss; requested module  main:Commands.OSX.Events differs from name found in the interface file commands-0.0.0:Commands.OSX.Events
```

here are some file contents:

```
$ cat Makefile
PACKAGES   = -package template-haskell -package language-c-quote -package language-c-inline -package commands
FRAMEWORKS = -framework Carbon -framework Cocoa -framework Foundation
LDFLAGS    = $(PACKAGES) $(FRAMEWORKS) 
Main: Main.o
    cabal exec -- ghc  -o Main Main.o $(LDFLAGS)
Main.o:
    cabal build
    cabal exec -- ghc  -c Main.hs -idist/build/ -v
...

$ cat commands.cabal
 exposed-modules: Commands.OSX.Events
 hs-source-dirs: sources
...

$ ghc --show-iface dist/build/Commands/OSX/Events.hi
interface commands-0.0.0:Commands.OSX.Events 7083
...

$ cat sources/Commands/OSX/Events.hs
module Commands.OSX.Events where
...

$ cat Main.hs
import Commands.OSX.Events
...
```

the cabal build is successful, and executable compiles and runs successfully, if I just put everything in the same directory, and ignore cabal.

1. can I tell GHC that some module is part of some package?
2. can I make a cabal executable, with these external dependencies?
3. any other solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

explicitly naming the modules package worked:

```
ghc -package-name commands-0.0.0
```

http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.1/html/users_guide/packages.html

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question